# how get number of twitter followers in wordpress

Tags: functions, wp-remote-get

I used function to get twitter followers

```
function twitter_count($twitter_user){
         $count = get_transient('twitter_count');
    if ($count !== false) return $count;
         $count = 0;
         $dataOrig = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show/'.$twitter_user);
   if (is_wp_error($dataOrig)) {
         return 'Error!!!';
   }else{
         $profile = new SimpleXMLElement ( $dataOrig );
         $countOrig = $profile->followers_count;
         $count = strval ( $countOrig );
         } 
set_transient('twitter_count', $count, 60*60*24); // 24 hour cache
return $count;
```

and I need replace `file_get_contents` for `wp_remote_get`
how realize it?

Comment: So your question is _not_ "How get number of twitter followers" but "How do I use `wp_remote_get`?

Answer (score 1):

You would replace this:

```
$dataOrig = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show/'.$twitter_user);
if (is_wp_error($dataOrig)) {
     return 'Error!!!';
}else{
     $profile = new SimpleXMLElement ( $dataOrig );
     $countOrig = $profile->followers_count;
     $count = strval ( $countOrig );
     }
```

With this:

```
$dataOrig = wp_remote_get('http://twitter.com/users/show/'.$twitter_user);
if (is_wp_error($dataOrig)) {
     return 'Error!!!';
} else {
     $profile = new SimpleXMLElement ( $dataOrig['body'] );
     $countOrig = $profile->followers_count;
     $count = strval ( $countOrig );
}
```

Note that `wp_remote_get` returns an array with the body of the page in `body`.

Edit: Using `wp_remote_retrieve_body`...

```
$dataOrig = wp_remote_get( 'https://twitter.com/users/show/'.$twitter_user );

if ( is_wp_error( $dataOrig ) ) {
  return printf( '%s: %s', $dataOrig->get_error_code(), $dataOrig->get_error_message );
} elseif( 
  empty( $dataOrig )
  OR 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $dataOrig )
  OR 'OK' !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $dataOrig )
) {
  return _e( 'Nothing available', 'your_textdomain' );
} else {
  $dataContent = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $dataOrig );
  $profile = new SimpleXMLElement ( $dataContent );
  $countOrig = $profile->followers_count;
  $count = strval ( $countOrig );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be [`wp_remote_retrieve_body()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body)?

Comment: @kaiser : Yes, I suppose it should be. I tend to have an issue with "helper function overkill". There is very little difference is what I did and what that does. I'll edit it though.

Comment: this replace return Error, I tried before posting the question

Comment: Try it with a generic address like `http://example.com`. It works fine. Post the actual data returned and not your informationless "Error!!!" string.

Comment: And, if you had tried this, why didn't you post _that_ code?

Comment: @gshft You know that showing your code and effort is a prerequisite to asking a question? Aside from that, doubling the effort of someone who tries to help you for free by hiding your own research is just (...).

Comment: s_ha_dum: Hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: last version return error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML

Comment: I altered the code a bit but I never got that particular error when testing.

Comment: of course you did not get that error, delete `if ( is_wp_error( $dataOrig ) )` and you get it. your code not working

Comment: Why would I delete code that needs that needs to be there? It does work. I tested with a known good `$twitter_user`. You are doing something wrong, not me.

Answer (score 0):

solved problem using json

```
    function twitter_count($twitter_user){
    $count = get_transient('twitter_count');
    if ($count !== false) return $count;
         $count = 0;
    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get( 'https://twitter.com/users/'.$twitter_user.'.json', array( 'sslverify' => false )));
    $json = json_decode( $response );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $dataContent ) ) {
    $countOrig = $json->followers_count;
    $count = strval ( $countOrig );
    } else {
    return _e( 'Error', 'your_textdomain' );
    }               
set_transient('twitter_count', $count, 60*60); // 1 hour cache
return $count;
}
```

Comment: This code is badly broken. If `wp_remote_get` returns an error object you will have a string of further errors since you don't check for `is_wp_error` until much too late and you check a variable that isn't set.